# validate DropdownlistFor help

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I couldn't get this code working. It's not displaying validation error message when I submit the form.

viewModel

```
    [Required] 
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

Create.aspx

```
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country,Model.CountryList, "--Select--")%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country,"*") %>
```

Comment: you should accept answers if they are helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
[Required]  
public string Country { get; set; }
```